# Why my count,Distinct and count of Distinct count is very slow in huge cluster in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very huge cluster 20  m4.Xlarge instances .
I have file size of 20GB and count of records in the file is 193944092.

From this file I need three info.
1. Total no of records 
2. Total no of distinct records 
3. Total no of distinct records based on one column (`FundamentalSeriesId`).

When I run below code it takes very long time .For counting total no of records it has taken 7 minutes .

But for Total no of distinct and Total no of distinct records of FundamentalSeriesId column it has taken very long time I mean I have cancelled the query because it was taking long time.

If any one can improve my code that would be great .Can I use cache or something else to get the info faster ?

This is what I am doing

```
    val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://kishore-my-bucket-trf/Fundamental.FundamentalAnalytic.FundamentalAnalytic.SelfSourcedPublic.2011.1.2018-02-18-1340.Full.txt.gz")
println("Total count="+rdd.count())

val header = rdd.filter(_.contains("FundamentalSeriesId")).map(line => line.split("\\|\\^\\|")).first()
val schema = StructType(header.map(cols => StructField(cols.replace(".", "_"), StringType)).toSeq)
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(!_.contains("FundamentalSeriesId")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|").toSeq)), schema)

println("distinct count="+data.distinct.count())

val data1=data.select($"FundamentalSeriesId")
println("count of distinct FundamentalSeriesId column="+data1.distinct.count())
```

My sample records are like this ..

```
FundamentalSeriesId|^|FundamentalSeriesId.objectTypeId|^|FundamentalSeriesId.objectType_1|^|financialPeriodEndDate|^|financialPeriodType|^|lineItemId|^|analyticItemInstanceKey_1|^|AnalyticValue_1|^|AnalyticConceptCode_1|^|AnalyticValue.currencyId_1|^|AnalyticIsEstimated_1|^|AnalyticAuditabilityEquation_1|^|FinancialPeriodTypeId_1|^|AnalyticConceptId_1|^|sYearToDate|^|IsAnnual_1|^|TaxonomyId_1|^|InstrumentId_1|^|AuditID_1|^|PhysicalMeasureId_1|^|FFAction_1
```

Comment: Try using accumulators for counting distincts . That should be faster

Comment: @RameshMaharjan accumulators ?...Let me search about that ..

Comment: @RameshMaharjan one example would be good ..

Comment: haven't used it myself too. but I know that distinct would require shuffling.

Comment: you traverse the entire dataset several times, you should look into caching. And I would rather use spark's csv module to load the data directly to dataframe instead to rdd first

Comment: @RaphaelRoth One example please ..

Answer (score 2):

Distinct is a common problem in Spark, use countApproxDistinct instead if you can.

Comment: @AtharvThakur yes, thats why its called `countApproxDistinct`

Answer (score 2):

Distinct count will move all the data into single Executor. So try to increase the Executor memory to max. It can reduce the time.

Try to cache the data. So we can eliminate the disk Io.

Comment: In your code add rdd.cache in the second line and set executor memory to 20 gigs and cores to 5

Comment: Upvoted for the good info ...No i have not tried .. don't have permission to create such cluster ..Let me have permission and then will update you ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://your_path").cache()
```

because when you start compute .count() spark reads file every time for every .count() function, but when you start use .cache() it will read file only once